# WPF Designer (in VS 2008 and VS 2010) crashes with Visual Studio

Tags: wpf

Good day all.

I have the following question:

WPF designer in both VS 2008 and VS 2010 crashes with Visual Studio when I try to edit UI form. Moreover, it crashes even when I try to save .xaml.cs file. Meanwhile, Winforms and Dataset UI editors work as usual. Are there other people met this issue? And how could I fix up this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried repairing the installation or re-registering DLLs?

Comment: While I have not experienced this particular crash myself, I have found that deleting the .suo file (in the same directory as the solution file) often "cures" Visual Studio woes (particularly if the file has become quite large).

Comment: I just did a visual studio installation repair (from the menu on the VS 2010 Install DVD), but, it did not help to fix this issue.

Comment: I see this a lot when working with WPF applications. Still no solution in sight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not the .suo file, try uninstalling Silverlight. I had problems with crushing VS2008 a year ago, and it was caused by Silverlight 2.0.

Comment: Good evening
Thank you for answers
But, I am inclined to say, that, deleting the .suo file and uninstalling Silverlight did not fix the issue.
Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your hardware meets the requirements of VS?

Feeding VS with better hardware can improve its behaviour a lot.

At least in my experience it seems to have an well noticable effect :)